# mysql join many to one table and display each 'many' record as an additional column

Tags: mysql, relations

I have a many to one table.

For example:

```
user_id, name
1, chris
2, john
```

and

```
user_id, item
1, apple, 
1, banana,
2, orange
```

How could I run a query that returns something like this:

```
user_id, item_1, item_2, item_3
1, apple, banana, null
2, orange, null, null
```

Would I need to do a sub query for each `item_n` column?

Comment: `group_concat` is what you looking for.

Comment: It's called pivoting and it's better to do it in the application than in the database. Do a join between user- and item- table, order by user_id. When you retrieve the result, keep track when user_id changes.

Answer (score 1):

As [Kondybas](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/7895/kondybas) suggests in his comment, you can use GROUP_CONCAT to concatenate the columns

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(item,',') as items 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY user_id
```

Note that all original columns is fit into one column in the answer.